# How to center vertically floated elements, problems with elements scaling, img elements size problems

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a simple game, and I've run into few problems I can't seem to solve:

1. I can't center vertically floated elements (`.stat` and `.clickable`).
2. Total height of all elements should fit exactly into screen height, however it goes beyond it.
3. Images differ a bit in their width depending on value I give them (at my screen they look the same at 32% or 29%, but on 30% upper one has slightly wider (and a bit blurry) right border).
4. Height property of img elements has no effect.

Here's my code (Images are 450px wide squares):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.statsBar,
.buttons {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
  height: 13%;
}
#score {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
#hp {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.stats:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.clickable {
  float: left;
  width: 29.33%;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.game {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #999999;
}
img {
  width: 32%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
#enemyHand {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-top: 5%;
}
#playerHand {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src='game.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="game">
    <div class="statsBar">
      <p id="score" class="stat">score: 0</p>
      <p id="hp" class="stat">hp: 3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="hands">
      <img id="enemyHand" src="paper.png">
      <img id="playerHand" src="scissors.png">
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <a id="paper" class="clickable" onclick="document.getElementById('playerHand').src='paper.png'">Paper</a>
      <a id="rock" class="clickable" onclick="document.getElementById('playerHand').src='rock.png'">Rock</a>
      <a id="scissors" class="clickable" onclick="document.getElementById('playerHand').src='scissors.png'">Scissors</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Floating and centering are rather mutually exclusive. If you want to center elements, then use display:inline(-block) instead of floating to get them “on the same line”.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with your first question. However I can help you with the second. I made some small changes to your code, but I don't have the image. Look at the code bellow. The game container now is set to max-height: 100%; and height: 100vh; that should help. (100vh means the hole page. I also made body overflow: hidden;, because I think scrolling isn't necessary. I made the buttons container to the bottom of the page.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.statsBar,
.buttons {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
  height: 13%;
}
.buttons {
  bottom: 0;
  clear:both;
}
#score {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
#hp {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.stats:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.clickable {
  float: left;
  width: 29.33%;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.game {
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #999999;
}
img {
  height: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
#enemyHand {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-top: 5%;
}
#playerHand {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

For the third question, we don't have the images...
For the height property try display: block; and no width then. Check your classed normally it should work.

I hope I helped you !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of flexbox in this case (note the scroll is generated by the snippet's viewport `height`, ideally it wouldn't even overflow, but if it did, `overflow: auto` is set just to handle it, you can comment it though based on your benefit):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.statsBar,
.buttons {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
  height: 13%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.hands {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  /* comment if content will never overflow */
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.clickable {
  float: left;
  width: 29.33%;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.game {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #999999;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
img {
  width: 32%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
/*#score {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
}*/

/*#hp {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
}*/

/*.stats:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}*/

/*#enemyHand {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-top: 5%;
}*/

/*#playerHand {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div class="statsBar">
    <p id="score" class="stat">score: 0</p>
    <p id="hp" class="stat">hp: 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hands">
    <img id="enemyHand" src="paper.png">
    <img id="playerHand" src="scissors.png">
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <a id="paper" class="clickable" onclick="document.getElementById('playerHand').src='paper.png'">Paper</a>
    <a id="rock" class="clickable" onclick="document.getElementById('playerHand').src='rock.png'">Rock</a>
    <a id="scissors" class="clickable" onclick="document.getElementById('playerHand').src='scissors.png'">Scissors</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code. I solve your question 1 and 2. I don't understand about your image issue.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.statsBar,
.buttons {
  display: table;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
  height: 13%;
  width: 100%;
}
#score,
#hp{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}
#score {
  /*float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;*/
  text-align: left;
}
#hp {
  /*float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;*/
  text-align: right;
}
.stats:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.clickable {
  /*float: left;*/ /*Float sould not use here */
  display: table-cell;
  width: 29.33%;
  /*margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;*/
  border: 5px solid #bfbfbf;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.game {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #999999;
}
img {
  width: 32%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
#enemyHand {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-top: 5%;
}
#playerHand {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src='game.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="game">
    <div class="statsBar">
      <p id="score" class="stat">score: 0</p>
      <p id="hp" class="stat">hp: 3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="hands">
      <img id="enemyHand" src="http://placehold.it/450x450">
      <img id="playerHand" src="http://placehold.it/450x450">
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <a id="paper" class="clickable" onclick="document.getElementById('playerHand').src='paper.png'">Paper</a>
      <a id="rock" class="clickable" onclick="document.getElementById('playerHand').src='rock.png'">Rock</a>
      <a id="scissors" class="clickable" onclick="document.getElementById('playerHand').src='scissors.png'">Scissors</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```